# select cell in different column in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Recently I am working on a puzzle game with react js. I want to select one cell in each column. but unfortunately, I did not do that. the code sample is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-water-kmdf8?file=/src/List.js). I would be so grateful If you can help me with it.

Comment: Do you want to selected a row id in every each column?

Comment: no, I want to select only one cell in each column

Comment: If i select '2' in column 2, the '2' in column 1 and 3 will selected?

Comment: no, it should not be selected

Comment: It's mean only one selected?

Comment: yes. and If i go to two column number  2 and select another cell, the last cell remain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239824/discussion-between-seyed-amir-mehrizi-and-wisnuaryadipa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your requirement, you need to save the selected column and row that is related.

You can see my code below, I've store related column and row into check State, after that just tweak a little condition on the `List` component to show `bg-danger` class. Furthermore, I removed `onClick` function on the `div` component a parent of the `List` component, because I think it's useless to do multiple function call at one time for the same action `onClick`

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import List from "./List";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState({});
  const [columnId, setColumnId] = useState(null);
  const refColumnId = useRef(columnId)
  refColumnId.current = columnId;
  const data = [
    { id: 1, listOfNumbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] },
    { id: 2, listOfNumbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] },
    { id: 3, listOfNumbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }
  ];

  const handleIndex = (column, row) => {
    setCheck({...check, [column]: row})
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div className="row">
        {data.map((data, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <List
                columnId={columnId}
                key={data.id}
                data={data.listOfNumbers}
                getIndex={handleIndex}
                check={check}
                id={data.id}
              />
              ;
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

List.js

```
const List = ({ data, getIndex, check, id, columnId }) => {
  const handleCardClick = (column, row) => {
    console.log("columnId : ", columnId);
    console.log("id : ", check);

    getIndex(column, row);
  };
  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-column">
      {data.map((number, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="card">
            <div
              className={`card-body ${
                check.hasOwnProperty(id) && index === check[id] ? "bg-danger" : ""
              }`}
              onClick={() => handleCardClick(id, index)}
            >
              <h3>{number}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```